# How do I use command like \onslide for tikz and text on different slides?

Tags: pause, feynmp-auto

I am to explain 5 basic steps of a process and have decided to use tikzpicture to explain it better. I have these five slides that contain texts as well as tikzpitures.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
chains,
positioning, 
shadows.blur, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    My explanation for first box is put here.

    My explanation for first box is put here.

    My explanation for first box is put here.

    My explanation for first box is put here.

    My explanation for first box is put here.
\end{block}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
    nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
    arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
    arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
        minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
        node contents={~}},
    box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
        minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
        on chain, join = by  arj},
    ]
    \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in   {Problem Identification
    }
    {
        \node (m\j) [box] {\i};
    }
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{~}
\caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    My explanation for the second box is put here.
    My explanation for the second box is put here.
    My explanation for the second box is put here.
    My explanation for the second box is put here.
    My explanation for the second box is put here.
    My explanation for the second box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
        nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
        arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
        arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
            minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
            node contents={~}},
        box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
            minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
            on chain, join = by  arj},
        ]
        \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
        \foreach \i [count=\j] in   {
            Problem Identification, Statistics
        }
        {
            \node (m\j) [box] {\i};
        }
        \end{scope}
        %\draw[arj] (m3) -- (m2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{~}
    \caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    My explanation for the third box is put here.
    My explanation for the third box is put here.
    My explanation for the third box is put here.
    My explanation for the third box is put here.
    My explanation for the third box is put here.
    My explanation for the third box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
        nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
        arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
        arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
            minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
            node contents={~}},
        box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
            minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
            on chain, join = by  arj},
        ]
        \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
        \foreach \i [count=\j] in   {
            Problem Identification, Statistics, Planning
        }
        {
            \node (m\j) [box] {\i};
        }
        \end{scope}
        \draw[arj] (m3) -- (m2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{~}
    \caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    My explanation for the fourth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fourth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fourth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fourth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fourth box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
        nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
        arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
        arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
            minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
            node contents={~}},
        box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
            minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
            on chain, join = by  arj},
        ]
        \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
        \foreach \i [count=\j] in   {
            Problem Identification, Statistics, Planning,
            Imple\-men\-ta\-tion of Plans
        }
        {
            \node (m\j) [box] {\i};
        }
        \end{scope}
        \draw[arj] (m3) -- (m2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{~}
    \caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
    My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
        nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
        arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
        arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
            minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
            node contents={~}},
        box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
            minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
            on chain, join = by  arj},
        ]
        \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
        \foreach \i [count=\j] in   {
            Problem Identification, Statistics, Planning,
            Imple\-men\-ta\-tion of Plans, De\-ve\-lop\-ment
        }
        {
            \node (m\j) [box] {\i};
        }
        \end{scope}
        \draw[arj] (m3) -- (m2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{~}
    \caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How do I use command like `\onslide` to programe it such that I will not have to write `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` 5 times while I still achieve the same result or even better?

Comment: Please comment if you need more explaination

Comment: One needs to know that text in each block is different and not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already defined the counter `\j` inside the `\foreach` loop it is enough to surround your nodes with `\only<\j->{...}`. This produces:

[image]

Here is your modified code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
chains,
positioning,
shadows.blur, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
\blindtext.
\end{block}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
        nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
        arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
        arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
            minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
            node contents={~}},
        box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
            minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
            on chain, join = by  arj},
        ]
        \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
        \foreach \txt [count=\j] in   {
            Problem Identification, Statistics, Planning,
            Imple\-men\-ta\-tion of Plans, De\-ve\-lop\-ment
        }
        {
            \only<\j->{\node (m\j) [box] {\txt};}
        }
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{~}
    \caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can also use constructions like `\only<\j+1>{...}` if you want to modify the "time" when the slides appear -- or change the initial value of the `\j` counter. Finally, you can instead use

```
\uncover<\j->{\node (m\j) [box] {\txt};}
```

if you want the nodes to stay in the same place on each slide:

[image]

**EDIT**

If, as indicated in the comments, the descriptive content also changes from slide to slide then you can use the same trick with `\only` and `\oncover` commands. Exactly which is best is partly a matter of taste and partly depends on your content but I would probably use `\uncover`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
chains,
positioning,
shadows.blur, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
  \uncover<1->{My explanation for the first box is put here.}

  \uncover<2->{My explanation for the second box is put here.}

  \uncover<3->{My explanation for the third box is put here.}

  \uncover<4->{My explanation for the fourth box is put here.}

  \uncover<5->{My explanation for the fifth box is put here.}
\end{block}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
        nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
        arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
        arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
            minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
            node contents={~}},
        box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
            minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
            on chain, join = by  arj},
        ]
        \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
        \foreach \txt [count=\j] in   {
            Problem Identification, Statistics, Planning,
            Imple\-men\-ta\-tion of Plans, De\-ve\-lop\-ment
        }
        {
            \uncover<\j->{\node (m\j) [box] {\txt};}
        }
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

**EDIT II**

If the complete block of text is changing from slide to slide then perhaps you want to a modifier on the block environments like:

```
\begin{block}{~}<only@1>
  My explanation for the first box is put here.
\end{block}
```

Again, the best way of doing this really depends on your actual content and is partly a matter of personal style. For example, you can use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
chains,
positioning,
shadows.blur, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}<only@1>
  My explanation for the first box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{block}{~}<only@2>
  My explanation for the second box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{block}{~}<only@3>
  My explanation for the third box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{block}{~}<only@4>
  My explanation for the fourth box is put here.
\end{block}
\begin{block}{~}<only@5>
  My explanation for the fifth box is put here.
\end{block}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
        nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
        arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
        arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
            minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
            node contents={~}},
        box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
            minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
            on chain, join = by  arj},
        ]
        \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
        \foreach \txt [count=\j] in   {
            Problem Identification, Statistics, Planning,
            Imple\-men\-ta\-tion of Plans, De\-ve\-lop\-ment
        }
        {
            \uncover<\j->{\node (m\j) [box] {\txt};}
        }
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption*{\textit{\textbf{Source:} Self Motivated}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Comment: You need to know that text in each block is different and not the same. thus, I have edited my MWE

Comment: @DanielJames Well, actually, rather than my needing to know this I'd say that it is more the case that the question needs to say this:) Should the descriptive content change completely from slide to slide or should it stay in place?

Comment: It should change from slide to slide

Comment: Yes I mean text should change from slide to slide, just as tikzpicture should change also.